# how to fetch data in react using redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux, redux-thunk

could you please tell me 
how to fetch data in react using redux ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/lYMwLM591

```
import { UPDATED_STORIES } from './actions';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function getTopStories(){
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get('data.json').then( res => {
      console.log(res ,"respone");
      dispatch(getTopStoriesAysnc(res))
    })

  }
};

function getTopStoriesAysnc(response){
  return {
    type: UPDATED_STORIES,
    payload: response
  };
}
```

Comment: When do you want to load the data?

Comment: on componet load I already write my code please check https://codesandbox.io/s/lYMwLM591

Comment: Have you got redux-thunk middleware?

Comment: not sure ..:( could you please check code

Comment: For a very simple application / widget, dispatching a loading action on componentDidMount is usually fine. If you need something more full featured, I actually wrote a lib for easily binding isomorphic data loaders to react components https://github.com/davnicwil/react-frontload

Comment: Your code looks all right to me. What is exactly the problem here? You are already calling `getTopStories` when the component is loaded.

Comment: I am not getting response on console. I will  get `json` resone

Comment: see I have 15 object in array but showing 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your react app is fine. The reason why you could not see the data is because of CORS issue. If you check your console, you will notice that 
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is missing. Since you don't have any access to the server code, you can't do anything about this.

However, you don't actually have to use axios for this. Since the data is in the same project, you can just import them. So your get_updated_stories will look like the following:

```
import { UPDATED_STORIES } from './actions';
import data from './data.json'

export default function getTopStories(){
  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log(data ,"respone");
    dispatch(getTopStoriesAysnc(data))
  }
};

function getTopStoriesAysnc(response){
  return {
    type: UPDATED_STORIES,
    payload: response
  };
}
```

See it live here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pYW4pkRYX

Comment: please share your code ..why I will not call this in `Hello ` component

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to come from here :

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
       index :state.counter
   }
}
```

`state.counter` doesn't exist, but `state.item` does. You need to write :

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
       index :state.item
   }
}
```

Comment: If it's supposed to fetch images and text about trains, it does work for me.